# How do I verify a PayPal IPN against a product price?

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I'm building a software delivery platform. I have a fully working custom IPN script with PayPal, written in PHP, but the problem I'm having is confirming price.

**Simply put, what is the algorithm for comparing the actual product price vs. the fields coming in from the PayPal IPN?**

I marked a product price at $1.00 USD, but the IPN coming in from Great Britain (using USD currency) said $1.20 for mc_gross, and the mc_fee said 0.34 (and no mc_shipping value). Note that this is a simple product -- no subscription, shipping, taxes, and other complexities.

So, since $1.00 doesn't match $1.20, and ($1.00 - $0.34 = $0.86 !== $1.00), I really don't know what the formula would be to confirm that price. This means that someone can take the PP button code, change the price, and purchase it. The IPN would then shrug its shoulders and accept that price unless I can find the trick to verify that price.

Note that I do pass a custom field that tells me what the product ID is and what quantity was purchased, such as 4pk widgets.

I looked at what it would take to make an encrypted payment button on the fly with PHP, and it requires a dedicated hosting plan with full root capability because it involves security certificates and several other factors. So, that doesn't look like a possibility to use here.

Comment: How many items have youy sent in the cart?

Comment: 1 item. It was worth $1.00 USD.

Comment: Can you try getting the value for $mc_gross_x = $_POST['mc_gross_1'];

Comment: In this case, because there's only one product, there's no _x. The $_POST values I have are mc_gross, payment_gross, payment_fee, and mc_fee, among others. I compared product price against mc_gross and they didn't line up. So, that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Making an encrypted payment button doesn't require full-root capability, although keeping your private certificate safe is easier with a dedicated host. You can check with your provider to see what protection they have in place to make sure others can't just enter your home directory and snoop around.

You can generate a private certificate on a local machine and upload it to your server. The server will need the `openssl` extension to perform the signing.

Comment: I didn't know this. Thanks for the tip. Will investigate.